# Devise update additional attributes without password confirmation.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Use Rails 4, Devise, Simple form. Read a lot about this, but for sure have no enough experience. I've made RegistrationController, custom views also exists. 
With this I have no problem with password confirmation, but all my params are unpermitted:

```
def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(params)
end
```

As I understand this should be decision, but have no any effect for me:

```
def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
      u.permit(:username, :first_name, :last_name, :price_plan_id, :email_notify, :msg_notify,
               :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
    end
  end
```

Maybe somebody can write whole conceptual answer about it?

Comment: did you put before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters in your registration controller?

Comment: @DileepNandanam It was so many iteration with this task. You are right, here I forgot  to put it. Many thanks, everything works. In my case callback is `before_filter :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]` Feel free to write the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the callback for those who missed.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, if: :devise_controller?
```

Answer (score 0):

In my model which Devise is assigned I have added these methods:

```
def skip_devise
  @skip = true
end

def password_required?
  !@skip.nil? ? false : super
end

def email_required?
  !@skip.nil? ? false : true
end
```

Your model will override `password_required?` and `email_required?` methods of Devise.

When I want my model to skip these validations I just run this:

```
my_model.skip_devise
my_model.save!
```